# Raised KeyError exception is being quoted twice

Tags: python

So I have a to string method in one of my classes:

```
def __str__(self):
    # some irrelevant code
    raise KeyError("aaa")
```

Then in my tests I do:

```
with self.assertRaises(KeyError) as cm:
    str(myobject)
self.assertEquals("%s" % cm.exception, "aaa")
```

I get this output:

```
self.assertEquals("%s" % cm.exception, "aaa")
AssertionError: "'aaa'" != 'aaa'
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When formatting a `KeyError` as a string, the representation of the offending key is included:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d[2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 2
>>> d["a"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'a'
```

The representation of a string includes the surrounding single quotes, so you should use

```
self.assertEquals("%s" % cm.exception, "'aaa'")
```

or the more straight-foward

```
self.assertEquals(str(cm.exception), "'aaa'")
```